# Certutil -restrict Error The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: certificate, digital-certificate, certutil

I am trying to get the certificates which are valid within the given date range:-

```
certutil –view –restrict "NotAfter<=July 31,2013 08:00AM,NotAfter>=July 20,2013 08:00AM" –out "RequestID,RequesterName"
```

**Reference** :- http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2008/04/24/how-to-determine-all-certificates-that-will-expire-within-30-days.aspx

I get the following error :-

> CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar kind of problem where while adding the certificate to store using command `CertUtil -addStore Mykey.cer` was getting the error that

> CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.

The problem was that is unable to locate the certificate or import it. So to resolve this i followed following things in (Administrator command prompt):--

1.Used `ss -root` in the end of MakeCert command .
[image]

2.Run the CertUtil command from the same location where i runned the makeCert command.
[image]